# How can I install IE7 or IE8 on a new PC that came with Windows 7 and IE9 installed?

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer-9

I have Windows 7 with Internet Explorer 9. However, I am trying to find a way to get IE 7 or 8 due to requirements for a job that does no allow IE9. Yet I can find no way to download them, as they do not list Windows 7 as a system under downloads for IE7 or IE8. I am unsure of uninstalling IE9 since this is a new PC and had no prior version, and I do not want to totally screw the system up. Can someone advise?

> Test: Internet Explorer: In order to meet the internet browser
>   certification requirement, you cannot have Internet Explorer 9
>   installed on your machine. For help with uninstalling Internet
>   Explorer 9 from your machine, please visit the online how-to at
>   Microsoft for assistance. Once it is uninstalled, your system will
>   automatically revert back to the previous version of Internet Explorer
>   that was installed prior to Internet Explorer 9.

Comment: if you run windows 7 pro or better, you might also want to take a look at running an older version of IE in [XP mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx)

Comment: It is a new PC that came with Win7 and IE9 installed. Never had IE8 Yes it is pro and I tried running it in XP mode but then was told XP was not allowed, when I reran test

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of the quoted question; he wants IE8, not IE7.

Comment: Thank you Harry for realizing that NO THIS IS NOT DUPLICATE QUESTION! It is a NEW PC, and it came with Windows 7 professional, 64 bit SP1 and  IE9, I did not download or update it to IE9. I need to get IE9 OUT. I want to know HOW, and if it is possible to install IE8. Personally I do not even like IE, i prefer chrome, but when they run the system check on me it detects the IE9 and I am told I need remove it.

Comment: @studiohack can you please reopen my question as it is NOT a duplicate. I have read the alleged duplicate and it is of NO HELP to me. I came here because I desperately need help. Getting this issue resolved is the difference between having and not having a job for me

Comment: Can you describe what gave you the error in the quoted text? Is it some software that requires that IE9 is not installed?

Comment: It is some type of system scan they use to check your system to see if it meets their tech requirements.

Comment: I don't want to open another duplicate question however I too would like to know if there is a solution for downgrading to IE8 on a new PC that came installed with IE9 by default.

Answer (score 1):

Is the issue that the application you need to access only supports ie8 and ie7?  If so, you can put ie9 into Compatibility View mode to render pages in the same way broken versions of ie would (it is the icon on the address bar that looks like a broken page).  If they also use browser detection to determine you are on ie9 and stop the application, you can change the way ie9 presents itself to the server, effectively pretending it is a [different version](http://www.door2windows.com/how-to-change-internet-explorer-user-agent-string-in-all-versions-of-internet-explorer-without-any-tool/)

With these two measures in place, it is effectively the same as using an older version without installing.

Did you ever have ie8 on this machine?  If so, it doesn't get uninstalled ([apparently](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-AU/windows7/how-do-i-install-or-uninstall-internet-explorer-9)), so uninstalling ie9 would be an option to get back to ie8.

Comment: It is a new PC that came with Win7 and IE9 installed. Never had IE8 Yes it is pro and I tried running it in XP mode but then was told XP was not allowed, when I reran test.

Comment: is this a SP2 install? or deployment (manufactures) or download. Did you check in the Updates? I  have read about many people have removed IE9 by uninstalling the update that brought it in?  Of course they did it before a lot of other updates had come in?  di you look in windows updates?